# Difference between asymptotic normalities of OLS and MLE

Tags: normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

Let's see the comparison below
[image]

Asymptotic normality is given by CLT for both cases. In MLE case, a variance of $\hat{\theta}$ is in distribution as $\frac{1}{I(\theta)}$, but in OLS case $\sigma^2Q_{xx}^{-1} n$ is not a variance of $\hat{\beta}$.

The second case seems to follow CLT well, however both cases are already proved and easily seen anywhere.

What is a difference here?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking.  What "difference" do you seek to explain? It is clear that $\sigma^2Q_{xx}/n$ *is* the variance of $\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta-\beta)$: that is precisely why it appears in the OLS equations!

Comment: @ whuber You are right. But in MLE case $\frac{1}{I(\theta)}$ is not a variance of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)$ but of $\hat{\theta}$. Can you see this?

Comment: Sure--but that's not what you have asked!  You are explicitly asserting an incorrect statement about OLS, rather than asking about the MLE result in the first line.  What, then, is your question?  Is it about the variance of $\hat\beta$ in OLS, about the asymptotic distribution of the MLE, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're asking here. Are you asking why the asymptotic distributions of the OLS and MLE estimators are different? If so, that's contingent upon distributional assumption.

The assumptions about the error term matter heavily in determining whether or not the OLS and MLE estimators coincide. When you make the assumption that the error terms are normally distributed, the $\hat{\beta}_{MLE}$ - the MLE estimates - are the same as the OLS, $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$, estimates.

The MLE approach asks you to
$max_{\beta_{0},\beta_{1},\sigma^{2}} \; {L(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1},\sigma^{2})} = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{(Y_{i}-\beta_{0}-\beta_{1}X_{i})^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}
$.

This holds for small samples. When you have large samples, this holds generally, i.e. the MLE and OLS are the same in the asymptotic sense. Note that general result doesn't rely upon normality though. It just hinges upon the fact that the draws of the estimates approach normality with large enough $n$. So, the formulas you posted are the same but the MLE is written implicitly.